# How to get Collection name from firebase to React Native Android?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to get all the collection names from my firebase that look like '18-05-2023', '21-05-2023', etc into my React Native View.
[image: this my view on my firebase]

But with my code fetchCollectionName() it's showing itemName and itemPrice instead.

[image: This is the pic of my code from line 16 and my terminal view after I run and console.log it]

if I try collectionData[0] it give me an error.

My expectation is that in the terminal it can displays like this:
18-05-2023

21-05-2023

The collection name is what I want to retrieve. How can I do this?

This is my full code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {firebase} from '../config';

function Firstpage() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1500000);
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const [inputAmount, setInputAmount] = useState('');
    const [collectionName, setCollectionName] = useState('');

    //this one is the code
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCollectionName = async() => {
            try{
                const collectionSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('18-05-2023').get();
                const collectionData = collectionSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
                if (collectionData.length > 0){
                    setCollectionName(collectionData);
                }
                console.log(collectionData);
            }catch (error){
                console.log('Error fetching collection name: ', error);
            }
        }
        
        fetchCollectionName();
    }, [])

    const handleEditAmount = () => {
        setIsEditing(true);
    };
  
    const handleAmountChange = (value) => {
        setInputAmount(value);
    };
  
    const handleAmountSubmit = () => {
        const newAmount = parseInt(inputAmount, 10) + amount;
        setAmount(newAmount);
        setInputAmount('');
        setIsEditing(false);
    };
          
    return(
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 80, backgroundColor: 'white', height: '100%' }}>
            <View style={styles.newBox}>
                <View style={styles.containerTotalMoney}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.amountMoney} onPress={handleEditAmount}>
                        <FontAwesome name='plus-circle' size={55} color='#546e27' style={{ }} />
                        {isEditing ? (
                        <TextInput
                            style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginLeft: 10 }}
                            value={inputAmount}
                            onChangeText={handleAmountChange}
                            keyboardType='numeric'
                            autoFocus={true}
                            placeholder='Input Nominal'
                            onSubmitEditing={handleAmountSubmit}
                        />
                        ) : (
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 30 }}>Rp{amount.toLocaleString()}</Text>
                        )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Addnew')}>
                    <Text style={styles.newButton}>New</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <ScrollView style={styles.listExpense}>
                {/* I give each collection a name like dd-mm-yyyy. I want the view below to retrieve the collection name from firebase.*/}
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detaillist')} style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.TitleDate}>{collectionName}</Text>

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight: 10 }}>Sun</Text>

                            <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>Rp10.000.000</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <View style={styles.ActionDate}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detaillist')}>
                            <FontAwesome name='pencil' style={styles.ActionText} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
                            Alert.alert(
                                'Delete Confirmation',
                                'Are you sure want to delete this?',
                                [
                                    {
                                        text: 'Cancel',
                                        style: 'cancel'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Delete',
                                        onPress: () => console.log('Item dihapus')
                                    }
                                ]
                            )}>
                            <FontAwesome name='trash' style={styles.ActionText} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={{ margin: 10 }}></View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Firstpage;
```

Comment: Well you have change your db structure . make a collection as `purchases` and in this make documents with date as name , then add an array of object containing your purchases or details

Purchases > 18-03-2015 > [ {name, price }, { name, price }]

Comment: There is no API in the client-side SDKs for Firestore to retrieve a list of collection names. You have to *know* the collection name, and then you can read the list of documents. As as Suyash commented, the common approach is to change your data model to match the API and your requirements.